# Latex not in outerpar mode

Tags: beamer, floats, errors, diagrams, compilation-error

Sorry if this is stupid, have no idea what latex is complaining about now

```
\newif\ifhandout
 \input{mytalk11.tex}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]   %  change to default  circle later
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage[algosection,ruled,lined,linesnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}

 \newcommand{\ECT}{\ensuremath{\textsc{ECT}}}

 \usepackage{dsfont}

 \def\theorem{\par\noindent{\bf Theorem.\ } \ignorespaces}

\usepackage{soul}
\newtheorem{nmbrs}[theorem]{Numbering}
\newtheorem{assump}[theorem]{Assumption}

\newtheorem{rem}[theorem]{Remark}

\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{alg}[theorem]{Algorithm}


\newtheorem{result}[theorem]{Result}

\newtheorem{coroll}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{theo}[theorem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem*{theoreem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

       \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.27]{pic1.png}
             \caption{}
        \label{onethird}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

\end{document}

```
mytalk.texcode:


%\handouttrue

\ifhandout
\documentclass[mathserif,11pt,handout]{beamer}
\else
\documentclass[onlymath,11pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\fi


\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathbbol}

\usetheme{boxes}

%colour definition
\definecolor{mylightblue}{RGB}{204, 230, 230} %Remark 
\definecolor{mydarkblue}{RGB}{0, 77, 77} %Remark Title

\definecolor{mylightpink}{RGB}{255, 217, 217} %Exercise
\definecolor{mydarkpink}{RGB}{166, 0, 0} %Exercise Title

\definecolor{mylightyellow}{RGB}{255, 255, 166}%Definition
\definecolor{mydarkbrown}{RGB}{125, 77, 0}%Definition Title

\definecolor{mylightpurple}{RGB}{217, 217, 255}%Theorem
\definecolor{mydarkpurple}{RGB}{0, 0, 128}%Theorem Title

\definecolor{mylightgreen}{RGB}{217, 255, 217}%Example
\definecolor{mydarkgreen}{RGB}{0, 128, 0} %Example Title

\definecolor{mygraydark}{RGB}{160,160,160}
\definecolor{mygraylight}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\definecolor{mybluedark}{HTML}{002239}
\definecolor{mybluelight}{HTML}{4FA2D7}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{BC9830}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{BE3100}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{044B7A}
\definecolor{myalertred}{HTML}{BE3100} %alert colour
\definecolor{approvedgreen}{RGB}{0,85,0} % #006E00

%title bar grey
%change structure colors
\setbeamercolor{blue text}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{green text}{fg=mydarkgreen}
\setbeamercolor{red text}{fg=myred}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mygraydark}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=myred}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black,bg=mybluedark}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=mybluedark,bg=mybluelight}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=mybluedark}
%\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=white}

%Add footline
\addfootbox{palette secondary}{\hfill\insertshorttitle\quad}
\addfootbox{palette tertiary}{\quad
  \insertsection 
  \ifx\insertsubsection\empty  \else  ~-- \insertsubsection \fi
}

%Titles
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\textcolor{mygraydark}{\textbf{#1}} \vspace{0.7em}}

%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%itemized and enumerated lists
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=black}

%create green box for examples
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{fg=mydarkgreen,
bg= mylightgreen}
\setbeamercolor*{block body example}{fg= black,
bg= mylightgreen}


%remark block
\newenvironment<>{remark}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue,bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{Remark} #1}
{\end{block}}

%remarks block
\newenvironment<>{remarks}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue,bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{Remarks} #1}
{\end{block}}

%Exercise block
\newenvironment<>{exercise}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpink, bg=mylightpink}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpink}%
\begin{block}{Exercise} #1}
{\end{block}}

%Definition block
\newenvironment<>{defn}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkbrown, bg=mylightyellow}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightyellow}%
\begin{block}{Definition} #1}
{\end{block}}

%Theorem block
\newenvironment<>{theorem}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Theorem} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{lemma}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Lemma} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{lem}[1]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpink, bg=mylightpink}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpink}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{cor}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Corollary} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{prop}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Proposition} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{claim}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpurple, bg=mylightpurple}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpurple}%
\begin{block}{Claim} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{thm}[1]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black, bg=mygraydark}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{mybox}[1]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black, bg=mygraydark}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

%Question block
\newenvironment<>{question}[1]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkpink, bg=mylightpink}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightpink}%
\begin{block}{Question} #1 #2}
{\end{block}}


\newenvironment<>{obs}[1]
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue, bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{#1} #2}
{\end{block}}

%recap block
\newenvironment<>{recap}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkblue,bg=mylightblue}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightblue}%
\begin{block}{Recap} #1}
{\end{block}}


\newenvironment<>{idea}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mydarkbrown, bg=mylightyellow}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mylightyellow}%
\begin{block}{Idea} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{myproof}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mygraydark, bg=mygraylight}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{Proof} #1}
{\end{block}}

\newenvironment<>{myproblem}
{\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=mygraydark, bg=mygraylight}%
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=mygraylight}%
\begin{block}{Problem} #1}
{\end{block}}

%
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bf Proof: }}{\qed}

%new Commands

% Sets
\newcommand{\A}{{\mathbb{A}}}
\newcommand{\C}{{\mathbb{C}}}
\newcommand{\N}{{\mathbb{N}}}
\newcommand{\Q}{{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\Z}{{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\mathbb{F}}}

% bases
\newcommand{\mA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\mB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\mC}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\mD}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\mP}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\mS}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\mT}{\mathcal{T}}


% vector spaces/subspaces
\newcommand{\vsD}{\mathbb{D}}
\newcommand{\vsL}{\mathbb{L}} % vector space of linear mappings
\newcommand{\vsP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\vsS}{\mathbb{S}}
\newcommand{\vsT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\vsU}{\mathbb{U}}
\newcommand{\vsV}{\mathbb{V}}
\newcommand{\vsW}{\mathbb{W}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathbb{W}}

% commonly used notations
\newcommand{\sys}[2]{\left[ #1 \mid #2 \right]}

% functions + special set operators
\newcommand{\real}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\imag}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}
\newcommand{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank }}
\newcommand{\spn}{\operatorname{Span}}
\newcommand{\proj}{\operatorname{proj}}
\newcommand{\prp}{\operatorname{perp}}
\newcommand{\refl}{\operatorname{refl}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}
\newcommand{\nul}{\operatorname{Null}}
\newcommand{\nully}{\operatorname{nullity}}
\newcommand{\range}{\operatorname{Range}}
\newcommand{\col}{\operatorname{Col}}
\newcommand{\row}{\operatorname{Row}}
\newcommand{\cof}{\operatorname{cof}}
\newcommand{\Num}{\operatorname{Num}}
\newcommand{\Id}{\operatorname{Id}}
\newcommand{\inj}{\operatorname{inj}}
\newcommand{\DOT}{\operatorname{DOT}}
\newcommand{\CROSS}{\operatorname{CROSS}}
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1, #2\rangle} % inner products

%vectors in R^n
\newcommand{\vzero}{\overrightarrow{0}}
\newcommand{\va}{\overrightarrow{a}}
\newcommand{\vb}{\overrightarrow{b}}
\newcommand{\vc}{\overrightarrow{c}}
\newcommand{\vd}{\overrightarrow{d}}
\newcommand{\ve}{\overrightarrow{e}}
\newcommand{\vf}{\overrightarrow{f}}
\newcommand{\vg}{\overrightarrow{g}}
\newcommand{\vh}{\overrightarrow{h}}
\newcommand{\vJ}{\overrightarrow{J}}
\newcommand{\vm}{\overrightarrow{m}}
\newcommand{\vn}{\overrightarrow{n}}
\newcommand{\vp}{\overrightarrow{p}}
\newcommand{\vq}{\overrightarrow{q}}
\newcommand{\vr}{\overrightarrow{r}}
\newcommand{\vs}{\overrightarrow{s}}
\newcommand{\vt}{\overrightarrow{t}}
\newcommand{\vtt}{\overrightarrow{t}\thinspace ^2}
\newcommand{\vu}{\overrightarrow{u}}
\newcommand{\vv}{{\overrightarrow{v}}}
\newcommand{\vw}{\overrightarrow{w}}
\newcommand{\vx}{\overrightarrow{x}}
\newcommand{\vy}{\overrightarrow{y}}
\newcommand{\vz}{\overrightarrow{z}}

\newcommand{\pfx}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}
\newcommand{\pfy}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}
\newcommand{\px}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}
\newcommand{\pxn}[1]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\py}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}}
\newcommand{\jacu}{\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}}
\newcommand{\jacx}{\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}}
\newcommand{\defbf}[1]{{\bf #1}}

%environments
\def\soln{\vskip10pt\noindent {\bf Solution:} }
%\newcommand{\lec}[1]{\vskip15pt\noindent\underline{\bf Lecture #1 :}\vskip10pt}
%\newcommand{\con}{\noindent\underline{Content:} \hskip5pt}
\newcommand{\prob}{\vskip10pt\noindent\underline{Problem:} \hskip5pt}
\newcommand{\ex}[1]{\vskip10pt\noindent\underline{Example #1:}\hskip7pt}
%\newcommand{\defn}{\vskip10pt\noindent\underline{Definition:}\hskip7pt}
\renewcommand{\note}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Note:}\hskip5pt}
\newcommand{\rema}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Remark:}\vskip5pt\noindent}
\newcommand{\notes}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Notes:}\vskip5pt\noindent}
\newcommand{\proofd}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Proof:}\hskip7pt}
\newcommand{\proofno}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Proof:}\thickspace}
\newcommand{\notation}{\vskip5pt\noindent{\bf Notation:}\vskip5pt\noindent}

%my stuff

\newcommand{\squeeze}[2]{
  \begin{center}\begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
   #2 \end{minipage}\end{center}}

\newcommand{\squeezenc}[2]{
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
   #2 \end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\cols}[4]{
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{#1\textwidth}  
      #3
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{#2\textwidth}
      #4
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  }

\newcommand{\ovl}[2]{
  \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{#1\textheight}
    #2
  \end{overlayarea}
}

\newcommand{\opt}{\ensuremath{\mbox{opt}}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{blue text} #1}}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{approvedgreen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{red text} #1}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathbb{0}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbb{1}}
% \newcommand{\st}{\mbox{s.t.}}

\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\newlength{\origitemsep}
\setlength{\origitemsep}{\itemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}
\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{1pt}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\setlength{\itemsep}{\wideitemsep}\olditem}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve by posting more than 400 lines of preamble code? Have you ascertained that the error message you're getting corresponds to any part of the code you posted?

Comment: @Mico  The second part following mytalk.texcode:  is just a template I've included it so things can compile  but I don't think that part needs analyzing, but I've included it so things can compile.

Comment: No that is not how you should use question posts. You should remove every line of the example that you can remove while still showing the error. that makes it **much** easier for people to help you.

Comment: the error is telling you that you have a `figure` environment where it is not allowed, but in beamer you don't normally have floating figures anyway, just use `\includegraphics` why wrap in `\begin{figure}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  can you not do figures in beamer?   I seem to recall being able to do figures in beamer.

Also If I remove the template it cannot compile so I kept it but I also indicated that it's just the first part.  Also in the past I have left that part out and someone asked to see that part so it could compile.

Comment: you should post an example that runs and shows the error but it should be minimal. Are you saying that you have to include the line `\definecolor{mylightpink}{RGB}{255, 217, 217} %Exercise` in this example otherwise the error does not occur? If you can remove it you should remove it otherwise anyone tracing tex execution has to step through that. and even if not it makes running your example unnecessarily time consuming. You just make it harder for people to help you.

Comment: you can normally have a figure environment in beamer (although it does nothing) but I am not going to check which of your packages is breaking that as you need to post a more reasonable example. You can delete packages until the error goes as easily as anyone else.

Comment: actually I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

The posted example is completely unreasonable. A minimal example, which you could have made by deleting code not used in the test document is

```
\documentclass[onlymath,11pt]{beamer}



\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

       \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.27]{example-image.png}
             \caption{}
        \label{onethird}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`beamer` does not support floats but it defines versions of `figure` and `table` that work like `[H]` floats from the float package and always typeset at the point of use.

The `floatrow` package is assuming a normal floating environment and defining `figure` in a way incompatible with `beamer`, you can simply delete it.

Comment: Now THAT is dedication!